# Is it possible to serialize a custom struct as an xml attribute?

Tags: c#, struct, xml-serialization, xml-attribute

Is is possible to serialize a custom struct as an xml attribute?

Sample code:

```
public class Dummy<T>
{
    private Dummy() { }
    public Dummy(T item1)
    {
        Item1 = item1;
        Item2 = item1;
    }

    public T Item1 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public T Item2 { get; set; }
}

public struct Meh
{
    public int Prop { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void XmlMehTest()
{
    var meh = new Meh{Prop = 1};
    var dummy = new Dummy<Meh>(meh);
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dummy.GetType());
        // System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot serialize member 'Meh2' of type Meh. 
        // XmlAttribute/XmlText cannot be used to encode complex types.
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dummy);
        Console.Write(writer.ToString());
    }
}

[Test]
public void XmlDateTimeTest()
{
    var dummy = new Dummy<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dummy.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dummy);
        Console.Write(writer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Please ignore that the struct is mutable, wrote it like that for a compact sample.

This is truly a [first-world-developer-problem](/questions/tagged/first-world-developer-problem) but I'm still curious :)

Comment: How do you expect the serializer to translate a class into a string for use in an attribute? It's not trivial.

Comment: I have no idea, just curious if it is possible to get it to work like for DateTime.

Comment: @Selman22 Isn't any struct a value type?

Comment: @Selman22 He's trying to serialize a `Meh` which is a value type. Look at the exception message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

*You can assign the XmlAttributeAttribute only to public fields or public properties that return a value (or array of values) **that can be mapped to one of the XML Schema definition** language (XSD) simple types (including all built-in datatypes derived from the XSD anySimpleType type). The possible types include any that can be mapped to the XSD simple types, including Guid, Char, and enumerations.*

So to do this, we should be able to create our own type definition for XSD,I guess we can do that.Because this [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#xr-defn) contains full explanation about it.But what we can't do is, we can't include our definition to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) list.Initially XML Serializer uses these types to figure out your type's XSD type definition.You can use this attribute with `DateTime` because it's definition creating with this method and storing in a HashTable:

```
AddPrimitive(typeof(DateTime), "dateTime", "DateTime", 
             TypeFlags.XmlEncodingNotRequired | 
             TypeFlags.HasCustomFormatter | 
             TypeFlags.CanBeElementValue | **TypeFlags.CanBeAttributeValue**);
```

`AddPrimitive` method:

```
private static void AddPrimitive(Type type, string dataTypeName, string formatterName, TypeFlags flags)
    {
        XmlSchemaSimpleType dataType = new XmlSchemaSimpleType {
            Name = dataTypeName
        };
        TypeDesc desc = new TypeDesc(type, true, dataType, formatterName, flags);
        if (primitiveTypes[type] == null)
        {
            primitiveTypes.Add(type, desc);
        }
        primitiveDataTypes.Add(dataType, desc);
        primitiveNames.Add(dataTypeName, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", desc);
    }
```

And this definition calling from `XmlReflectionImporter` like this (which is generating the exception according to StackTrace):

```
this.GetTypeDesc(name, ns, TypeFlags.CanBeElementValue | TypeFlags.CanBeTextValue | TypeFlags.CanBeAttributeValue);
```

I guess most important thing is here `TypeFlags.CanBeAttributeValue` and I think it's specify that this type can be attibute value.So as a result maybe we can serialize custom structs as an `XmlAttirube` but we can't do it with standart `XmlSerializer`.Because as I said it's using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.datatype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) list to figure out XSD type definition.And it's an initial list and it's impossible to add new element to that list.

P.S. You might want take a look at here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8w07bk3h(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yep +1, will leave it open for a wile though.